# Controller method call expected when compiling a Play Framework application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am getting an error message when compiling my application.

My Routes file looks as below:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)


# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index
GET     /listing/create                         Application.createAuctionItem
POST    /listing/create                         Application.doCreateItem
GET     /listing/show                           Application.show
GET     /search                                 Application.search

GET     /rss/recent                             Application.recentlyAdded(format:'rss')
GET     /recent                                 Application.recentlyAdded

GET     /signup                                 Authenticate.register
POST    /signup                                 Authenticate.doRegister

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

My application (Java) looks like the below:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import models.*;
import java.util.List;
import play.data.validation.*;
import static play.modules.pdf.PDF.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

   public static void recentlyAdded() {
      List<AuctionItem> recentlyAdded = AuctionItem.recentlyAdded(50);
      render(recentlyAdded);
   }


   public static void showPDF(Long id) {
      AuctionItem item = AuctionItem.findById(id);
      item.viewCount++;
      item.save();
      renderPDF(item);
   }

   public static void showImage(Long id) {
      AuctionItem item = AuctionItem.findById(id);
      renderBinary(item.photo.get());
   }

   public static void search(String search, Integer page) {

      validation.required(search).message("You must enter something to search for");
      if (validation.hasErrors()) {
         render();
      }

      if (page == null) page = 1;
      SearchResults results = AuctionItem.search(search, page);
      render(results, page, search);
   }

   public static void show(Long id) {
      AuctionItem item = AuctionItem.findById(id);
      item.viewCount++;
      item.save();
      render(item);
   }

   public static void doCreateItem(@Valid AuctionItem item) {
      // if there are errors, redisplay the auction form
      if (validation.hasErrors()) {
         params.flash();
         validation.keep();
         createAuctionItem();
      }

      // set the user based on the logged in user
      item.createdBy = Authenticate.getLoggedInUser();

      // if no errors, save the auction item and redirect to the show page
      item.save();
      show(item.id);
   }

   public static void createAuctionItem() {
      if (session.get("user") == null) {
         Authenticate.login();
      }
      render();
   }

   public static void index() {
      List<AuctionItem> mostPopular = AuctionItem.getMostPopular(5);
      List<AuctionItem> endingSoon = AuctionItem.getEndingSoon(5);
      render(mostPopular, endingSoon);
   }
}
```

I am getting the following error when I compile the code:

```
[error] D:\Paly SampleApps\Chapter4\conf\routes:6: Compilation
 error[Controller method call expected]
[error] GET     /listing/create                         Application.createAuctio
nItem
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createAuctionItem` method must return a `Result` not `void`

cf. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaActions

Answer (score 1):

Also, you got to use the "*controllers*" namespace, like this

```
GET     /listing/show                           controllers.Application.show
```